# How do I send a POST request to my server on button click using retrofit API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

I want to send a request to my `php` server script and `log`  the response that I receive. I am new to Flutter and this is what I have done till now:

1. I had included all the required dependencies in my **pubspec.yaml**
2. After that, I created a new abstract class which contains my headers and my target url:

***post_retro.dart***:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

part 'post_retro.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: "http://web_url_here/")
abstract class RestClient {
  factory RestClient(Dio dio) = _RestClient;

  @POST('server_first.php')
  Future<Response> fetch_info([
    @Header("input") String input,
    @Header("pf") String pf,
    @Header("pan") String pan
  ]);

  @POST('server_second.php')
  Future<Response> fetch_emp_data([
    @Header("input") String input,
    @Header("pf") String pf
  ]);
}
```

3. After that, I ran the command `flutter pub run build_runner build` in my terminal.

I have no idea what to do after this. I have a `button` in my `main.dart` which when clicked, should send the request data to my server and `log` the response received.

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.teal, // Background color
  ),
  label: const Text('Fetch data'),
  icon: const Icon(Svgrepo.fetch_records),
  onPressed: () {
     if(nameController.text.isNotEmpty || passController.text.isNotEmpty){

          //send the request here
     }
     else{
        const snackBar = SnackBar(
           content: Text("Please don't leave any field empty"),
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
     }
  }
)
```

How do I send the request? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the concept of making abstract class but you can make a method like this and call it in your button

```
Future<String> postRequest({
    required String endpoint,
    required Map<String, dynamic> body,
    required bool tokenRequired,
  }) async {
    Response? response;
    try {
      String? token = await LocalStorageService().getToken();
      Uri uri = _getUri(endpoint);
      response = await post(
        uri,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          'Charset': 'utf-8',
          'Authorization': tokenRequired ? 'Bearer $token' : "",
        },
        body: json.encode(body),
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
      );
      if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
        return response.body;
      } else {
        _postError(
          endpoint: endpoint,
          statusCode: response.statusCode,
          body: response.body,
        );
        return "";
      }
    } catch (ex, stackTrace) {
      String responseStr = 'No Response';
      if (response != null) {
        responseStr = response.body;
      }

      _postError(
        endpoint: endpoint,
        statusCode: response?.statusCode ?? 0,
        body: responseStr,
      );
      return "";
    }
  }
```